# How can I list how many files are in each directory in OSX terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, command

How can I list how many files are in each directory together sub-directoies?

i found that:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | wc -l
```

but this is count all. 
I need the count for each sub-directory separately

Expected sample result is:

```
home/folder1 12
home/folder2 10
home/ 22
etc/folder1 100
etc/folder2 200
etc/folder3 10
etc 310
...
```

Is there a way I can count the number of files in each directory like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop over your directories and find `.txt` files inside each of them

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'echo -n "{} " && find {} -name "*.txt" | wc -l' \;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @gogaz. It is returning too much zero how can i prevent this?

Comment: Use an [`if` statement](http://codewiki.wikidot.com/shell-script:if-else)